# How to write script in Android for various task

Tags: android, scripting

I have rooted android phone and I am getting the # when I use "su" i wish to write a script that would keep running in background like service at application end and do the needful task for me. Where should i keep the .sh fle so that it will run on system boot so that no body will able to kill it ... i mean it should work like system service/apps ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write a script and save it either data/local/tmp/example.sh and it should like that
example.sh

```
#!/system/bin/sh

cd /data/local/tmp

while true; do


for i in *.apk ; do
    if ls $i 2> /dev/null >/dev/null ; then 
        echo "`date` : Found new $i " >> /data/local/tmp/update_log


    fi
done



sleep 120
reboot 


sleep 180
done
```

and add it to any .sh file which is run on boot of the device  it will check for any apk on data/local/tmp folder and create a list of that as update_log i put it on /data/local/tmp
and bind it with init.wlan.sh on the last line with & ..hope it works for you

Comment: now I want the script to catch other intent broadcast by the system and then i will do the needful as i do in onReceive method of broadcast receiver......